# How to use Google Tag Manager with history changes?

Tags: react-router, google-tag-manager

I am trying to delpoy Google Tag Manage for Facebook Pixel on a website that is using "React" and "React Router"  that is not mine and I don't have access to source.

I am using "History Change" trigger and checks for certain url changes. Then whenever user visits that page I get some data using queryselectors and send pixel event.

The issue is the tag gets fired very early when the old page is still loaded and javacript queryselector returns data from the previous page , this goes on with all subsequent link clicks.

Here is the code that I am using:'

```
  <script>
        var prodIdElement = 
    document.querySelector("span[itemprop=productId]");
        var product_id = prodIdElement.textContent;
        console.log(product_id);
        fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
            content_type: 'product',
            content_ids: [product_id]
        });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

We successfully use the "history changed".
Within our pages, the user can paginate between several detail pages. Let's say you have a search form, filter your items then click one item and navigate "horizontally" through these results.
Switch from detail to another one is done by javascript:

```
history.pushState({}, 'my Detail', "http://foo.bar");
```

[open detailview via JS and paginate to next detailview via JS => 2 history changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD5ws.jpg)

In case you haven't, switch to preview mode in GTM so see GTM's debug panel on your test page. With that you should see all event (tag being fired/ NOT being fired, dataLayer variables and so on...).

A detailed list of triggers that will activate history listeners (and a lot more), you can find here (thanks to Simo): https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/google-tag-manager-history-listener/

Hope that may help you.